# Locally compact topological group is paracompact

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, paracompactness

Let $G$ be a locally compact, connected topological group.Show that $G$ is paracompact.

Comment: I know this question lack any self made attempts, but still a score of $-4$ seems excessive.

Comment: After my upvote, it's -1 now.

Answer (score 6):

Let $U$ be an open (symmetric) neighbourhood of $e$ with compact closure and note 
that the subgroup $U$ generated by $U$, can be written as $\bigcup_n U^n$, and is an open subgroup of $G$ (as it has non-empty interior) and hence also a closed subgroup (standard fact), and so it equals $G$ by connectedness.

As $G =\bigcup_n U^n = \bigcup_n \overline{U}^n$ we see that $G$ is thus $\sigma$-compact and hence Lindelöf and a Lindelöf regular space is (strongly) paracompact.

We can even dispense with connectedness altogether: by a non-trivial structure theorem for locally compact topological groups, all such Hausdorff groups
are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n \times K \times D$, where $n$ is a finite integer, $D$ a discrete space and $K$ a compact Hausdorff topological group.

As $\mathbb{R}^n \times D$ is metrisable (hence paracompact) and the product 
of a paracompact and a compact space is paracompact, we are done.
But this theorem might be overkill, the connectedness idea is more elementary.

Comment: How to prove that $\bigcup_n U^n$ is closed?

Comment: @EdwardGrammer an open subgroup is closed: its complement is a union of open cosets.

Comment: Yes,I get it!TNX!!!

Comment: There is the hint of the problem :Let $U_{1}$ be a neighborhood of $e$ having compact closure.In general ,define $U_{n+1}=\overline{U}_{n}\cdot U_{1}$.Show the union of the sets $\overline{U}_{n} $is both open and closed. My Question:how to prove the union of the sets $\overline{U}_{n}$ is cloesd ?

Comment: @EdwardGrammer show the union is a subgroup (it’s the same as mine) and hence open (as it has non-empty interior, containing $U_1$), and this closed too by my previous argument. So my answer unwittingly followed the same proof idea.

Comment: In the hint I post,$U_{1}$ must be symmetric?

Comment: @EdwardGrammer it’s better to do so, to get a subgroup.

Comment: If  $ U_{1}$ (the neighborhood of $e$ )is not symmetric，then can we draw the conclusion that $H=\bigcup_n \overline{U}_{n}$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @EdwardGrammer how else do we get closedness under inversion?

Comment: So,it is an necessary condition.TNX!!!

Comment: Where can the proof of the structure theorem for locally compact topological groups be found?